# Memoization coin change in python(recursive solution)

Tags: python, recursion, optimization, memoization

I'm fairly new to python and I was practicing a couple of problems that I found online (This one is eulerproject q31). I have figured out 2 methods to solve it.
The problem: Find out all the ways you can make change for a given amount of money using a certain coin set e.g the dollar `{1,5,10,25}`

This is the code that I have for my recursive solution

```
def count(s, m, n):
    if (n < 0):
        return 0;
    if (m <=0 and n >= 1):
        return 0
    if (n == 0):
        return 1
    return count( s, m - 1, n) + count(s, m, n-s[m-1] );
```

S is the coin set `{1,5,10,25}`
m is the length of the coin set (which is 4 in this case) and n is the input amount

This works perfectly except for when I try to give it a larger value like 7000, I looked it up online and it seems that my solution will include sub-problems that were included in the previous recursive iteration multiple times (Making it reach the maximum recursion limit). I'm trying to figure out how to go about doing this using memoization which I would be able to Java but have no idea how to approach in python. Can anyone provide any guidance as to how I should memoize this algorithm so that it skips checking subproblems that were already checked? Thanks!

Comment: Memoization may be an option but this looks like a classic use for dynamic programming. `functools` has [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#functools.lru_cache) which is a memoization decorator that you can use.

Comment: @lru_cache I already implemented a dynamic solution, I'm trying to challenge myself by making the recursive one where the time complexity is not exponential.  I just have don't know too much about memoization.

Comment: Try clicking on the `lru_cache` link above.

Answer (score 0):

Store the amount you have computed.

```
def make_change(coins, n):
    dic_ways = {}

    def helper(index, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        if n < 0:
            return 0
        num_ways = 0
        for i in range(index, len(coins)):
            coin = coins[i]
            if n - coin not in dic_ways:
                num_ways += helper(i + 1, n - coin)
                dic_ways[n-coin] = True
        return num_ways

    return helper(0, n)
```

As you can see, n is the amount. When you encounter an amount that has been computed, you just skip it.

Comment: This isn't very useful because the `dic_ways` dictionary is not shared between recursive calls. You should probably make it an argument to the function, so you can pass it around as needed, only producing it from scratch on the first call.

Comment: @Blckknght You are right, I have moved out `dic_ways` out the function to share.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math
def memoization(coins,amount) :
    dp = {}

    def dfs(amount):
        if amount in dp:
            return dp[amount]
        if amount == 0:
            return 0

        res = math.inf
        for coin in coins:
            if (amount - coin) >= 0:
                res = min(res,1 + dfs(amount - coin))
        dp[amount] = res
        return res

    res = dfs(amount)
    return res if res != math.inf else -1

#Driver code
coins = [1,2,5]
n = 11
memoization(coins,n)
```

Comment: Please, add description of what is done.

Comment: Look at this final dp[] value {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 2, 11: 3}, here the key is amount and value is minimum coins required for that amount. Here we are using for loop and inside we are using recursion  if (amount- coin value) >=0 just to check for each coins combination whether  we are able to make that amount or not , and saving the minimum coins required for that amount in dp.